# How to modify a DB2 view query without dropping and creating view

Tags: db2

I need to modify the query of a DB2 view without dropping and creating that view.

I use DB Visualizer and I tried the ALTER VIEW command but I got the error "unexpected token 'VIEW' was found following 'ALTER'.

Any idea on how to resolve this problem?

Comment: AFAIK, Modifying the View query ultimately means, Dropping and recreating the view.

Comment: You cannot alter a view , (you can drop it or create it). However, you can *create a new view with a different name* if you have the right permissions and SELECT from the new view.

Comment: "_I need to modify the query of a DB2 view without dropping and creating that view._" -- Why?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [CREATE or REPLACE view](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0053738.html) functionaliy - it is also call soft invalidation and desribed in detail on the page referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Here would be a sample script, how to modify a view.  It works fine without any error on V11.5 GA, AIX 7.1.

```
#!/bin/sh

db2 -v "drop db db1"
db2 -v "create db db1"
db2 -v "connect to db1"
db2 -v "create table t1 (c1 int, c2 char(10), c3 char(10))"
db2 -v "insert into t1 values (1, 'aaa', 'AAA')"
db2 -v "insert into t1 values (2, 'bbb', 'BBB')"

db2 -v "create view v1 as select c1, c2 from t1"
db2 -v "select * from v1"
db2 -v "create or replace view v1 as select c1, c2, c3 from t1"
db2 -v "select * from v1"

db2 -v "terminate"
```

The first **select * from v1** returns **2 columns** but second one returns **3 columns** sice it's replaced with a new v1.

Hope this helps.